# AngularJS : Directive not picking up attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have got the following directive:

```
app.directive('ngAvatar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<img class="avatar-medium" ng-src="{{url}}" />',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs);
      var aType = attrs.avatarType;
      var aId = attrs.avatarId;
      console.log("Type: "+ aType);
      console.log("Character ID:"+ aId);
      var baseUrl = "http://api-character.com/";
      switch(aType){
        case "character":
          scope.url = baseUrl + "Character/"+aId+"_256.jpg";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Unfortunately the directive is not picking up the avatar_id inside of the directive.  As you can see I am console logging the attributes:

```
console.log("Type: "+ aType);
console.log("Character ID:"+ aId);
```

In my view I am using this directive like so:

```
<ng-avatar avatar_type="character" avatar_id="{{character.character_id}}"></ng-avatar>
```

The following is the output of my console in Chrome.  As you can see the avatar_id is showing as blank but on inspection of the `attrs` you can see that the attribute is there but just not showing in the directive code.

Chrome Console:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why it would not work?

Thanks

Comment: avatar_type is working fine as you can see from the console output.  avatar_id is not being picked up though.

Comment: Your console shows both the values. What is the issue? avatar_id is see populated with number

Comment: You need to use - not _. You can see it in the console probably because it is normalized to avatar_type not avatarType.

Comment: Ok.  I will change it but as you can see from this line console.log("Type: "+ aType); it outputs the correct data.  However the line console.log("Character ID:"+ aId); is not outputting the data.  The issue is with console.log("Character ID:"+ aId); not console.log("Type: "+ aType);

Comment: You must be setting the value to `character` asyncronously. Are you?

Comment: I am setting the character via an ajax request, yes!

Comment: ofcourse then Directive would have rendered before you populate the value right? do not console.log(attrs) it will do lazy expansion in chrome console and you will see the value at the time it is expanded.

Comment: I thought about this but you can  in the console log of the attrs that avatarId is set, so it must be due to the ajax request.  With directives how can I rememdy this?

Comment: Just setup a one time watch.

Comment: I found it.  Thanks.  Can you leave it as an answer and ill make it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many ways to solve this problem.

**using one time watch** - you could also consider using two-way bound isolated scoped directive

```
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
      //Set up watch
      var unWatch = scope.$watch(attrs.avatarId, function(v){
        if(v){
          unWatch();
          init();
        }
      });
     function init(){
       //initialize here
     }
   }
```

and bind it as:

```
   <ng-avatar avatar-type="character" avatar-id="character.character_id"></ng-avatar>
```

**Use attribute observe**

```
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
      //Set up watch
      var unWatch = attrs.$observe(attrs.avatarId, function(v){
        if(v){
          unWatch();
          init();
        }
      });
     function init(){
       //initialize here
     }
  }
```

and use it with

```
 <ng-avatar avatar-type="character" avatar-id="{{character.character_id}}"></ng-avatar>
```

**Bind promise/data**

```
  app.directive('ngAvatar', function($q) {
   //...
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
      //Set up watch
     $q.when(scope.$eval(attrs.character)).then(init); 

     function init(character){
       var id = character.id;
       //initialize here
     }
    }
  }
```

and bind it as

```
 <ng-avatar avatar-type="character" avatar-id="characterPromiseOrCharObject"></ng-avatar>
```

**Event bus**

Just use angular event bus and broadcast an event from the controller which sets the data say `char_loaded`, listen for the event in the directive using scope.$on and once you get it initialize.

Comment: Awesome answer, provided a solution to my problem and gave more insight into $watch!  Thanks